# Moving Files in MSOffice Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am attempting to create a button on one of my forms in Access that will move a file from one folder to another.  The filepath of the item is stored in the database.  My current approach is using VB and is displayed here.

```
Private Sub Command21_Click()
    Dim d As Database
    Dim r As Recordset
    Dim path As Field
    Dim fromPath As String
    Dim toPath As String
    Set d = CurrentDb()
    Set r = d.OpenRecordset("Documents")
    Set path = r.Fields("Action Items Location")
    While Not r.EOF
        fromPath = path
        Set toPath = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetParentPath(fromPath) 'Error line
        toPath = toPath & "\to folder"
        My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile fromPath, toPath
    Wend

End Sub
```

I keep getting an error saying object required on the line marked Error line.  How do I fix this error, or am I even going about it the correct way?

Comment: Try without 'Set' or look at the possible error exceptions here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b573ycc1(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Originally had it without 'Set' and it still had the same error.  I actually added set after reviewing this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251554.aspx

Comment: Are you using VBA or VB?  It seems from that link that `My.Computer.FileSystem.GetParentPath()` is a VB function perhaps not found in VBA.

Comment: I am actually using VBA, I was a bit confused on the difference/relationship, this is my first time writing any VB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the replies, though after a bit more research, and the suggestion of @Basdwarf, I was able to find a solution.  Here's the finished code

```
Private Sub Command21_Click()
    Dim d As Database
    Dim r As Recordset
    Dim path As Field

    Dim fromPath As String
    Dim toPath As String
    Dim fileName As String

    Dim filesystem As Object

    Set filesystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
    Set d = CurrentDb()
    Set r = d.OpenRecordset("Documents")
    Set path = r.Fields("Action Items Location")

    fromPath = path
    fileName = filesystem.GetFileName(path)
    toPath = filesystem.GetParentFolderName(filesystem.GetParentFolderName(fromPath)) & "\to folder" & "\" & fileName
    MsgBox (fromPath)
    MsgBox (toPath)
    FileCopy fromPath, toPath
    Kill fromPath
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

GetParentPath is not an available method in the VBA.Filesystem class in Access.
Go into Code, View, Object Browser, search Filesystem for available methods.

You can use GetFileInfo to find the files directory.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on the Object Browser, didn't know that was there.  I however, could not the GetFileInfo function.